# Server to server OAuth

Tags: node.js, google-drive-api, google-sheets-api, google-authentication, google-auth-library-nodejs

I want to create google spreadsheet everyday automatically from server side.
Google spreadsheet requires OAuth to Create, edit, delete spreadsheet. To get OAuth access token we have to manually signin and allow permission on consent screen. This is not possible on server side. Is there any way to get OAuth token server side? I am using Node.js on server side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Manual signin is required only once. After first user authorization you can save token (in database for example) and use it on your server to access Google API. See https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer